# C# data allocation problem

Tags: c#, c++, free, allocation

I have the following problem. I have a C++ dll, containing the function

```
void cpp_send (void *data_, size_t size_, free_fn *ffn_)
{
    //sends data
}
```

then I have C# dll that has a class

```
public class CS_dll : IDisposable
{
    void cs_send (void *data)
   {
       IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (data.Length);
       Marshal.Copy (data, 0, ptr, data.Length);
       try
       {
            cpp_send (ptr,
            Convert.ToUInt32 (data.Length), Free);
       }
 catch
 {
     Free (ptr);
 }
}
```

//The function Free () looks like:

```
public static void Free (IntPtr ptr)
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal (ptr);
}
```

I call it from  C# aplication as

```
CS_dll w = new CS_dll();
byte [] msg = new byte [msg_size];
w.cs_send (msg, msg_size);
```

The problem is, that after some time, the C# aplication crashes with SystemAccessViolationExcetpion.
Do you have any idea where the problem is?

To make it clearer: The C# aaplication can finish for some types of input while for the others it crashes, so I dont thing there is problem with calling convention, is there?

Comment: send function:= cs_send(msg,msg_size)?

Comment: What line of code is causing the AccessViolationException?

Comment: AVs are caused by unmanaged code.  Your cpp_send() function, most likely.  Code you didn't post.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending 5 parameters to a function that receives only 3?

Edit: Thanks for fixing the code. You say it fails with some types of data. Can you say which type?

Comment: it depends on how many messages I try to send, it crashes with about 100000, but works fine for all bellow.

Comment: Maybe the C++ process can't allocate a pointer for so many quantity of data? Did it worked by itself?

Answer (score 0):

What is 'data.Length' ?  Please provide the defition where data is declared.

UPDATE: It could also be the callback (delegate) you are passing into the function is using the stdcall, while the unmanaged function is expecting a cdecl calling convention.